# Understanding, jquery-ui-autocomplete, does someone could try to explain me this code please?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Well I just implement jquery-ui-autocomplete with VB.net in the server side, but it was because I follow an example, does anybody could try to explain (for dummys) how it works this code ?, the part I have no idea about it is in the return (success event):

```
$("#kSerial").autocomplete({
           source: function (request, response) {
               dataFromServer = "";
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: URL + 'regresaSeriales',
                   async: false,
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   data: "{" + "'serial':'" + request.term + "'" + "}",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function (msg) {

                       /*This is the part I just don't get it*/                        

                       response($.map(msg.d, function (item) {
                           return {
                               value: item.serial
                           };
                       }));

                     /*and ends here*/

                   },
                   error: function () {

                       serial = 0;

                   }

               })

           },
```

On my server side I return a list of "serial" objects (List (of T)) and it works fine.

I just follow an example and adapted to my server side code, but I have no idea about how it works the part of the return, I mean I understood that the "source" property accepts a callback, but can't realize how it works the code in the success event of the ajax request.

Indeed I neither get the reason of the  2 parameters in the callback, especially the "request",  (request,response).

This is the tutorial I based my code: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=515

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes the response data, grabs the `d` object property (an array), iterates over it, and for each item in that array, creates an object with a `value` property of the item's `serial` property.

The [`$.map` call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) puts all those objects in to an array and sends it to the `response` function (IIRC part of the autocomplete plugin that spits out the completions).

The `request` parameter is just an object containing the search term, or "what's in the text input". This is described in the [autocomplete overview docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#overview).

Comment: hi thanks, then the "magic" it's about how the $.map well I should learn more about it, thanks by your explanation.